# Angular filtered result not updating in the UI

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I have this filter for moment:

```
function momentFilter() {
  return function(input, format) {
    if (!input) return null;

    if (format == 'fromNow') {
        var fn =  moment(input).fromNow();
        console.log('fromNow called with: ' + input + ' giving result: ' + fn);
        return fn;
    } 
  };
}
```

And I have this html:

```
<div>{{timestamp | moment: 'fromNow'}}</div>
```

I see the filter getting called on the digest cycle, and the relative time that gets logged in the console looks great.  I.E. it goes from 1 minute ago, 2 minutes ago, etc...  However the UI never updates to what the filter returns.

The first call is reflected on the UI, but after that the UI never updates.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

That html is inside an ng-repeat that tracks by id.  I am assuming that because nothing in the object actually changed (current time just moved), that angular never detects anything for that object.

Still not sure how to work around this.

Answer (score 0):

did you try by changing object hash? normally if you change object hash code framework will understand object is modified and rendered updated object.

Comment: I could do that but I don't really want to change the object.  It didn't really change.  The timestamp on the object is the same, it just that real time just keeps moving forward.  That means I have to attach a timer or something to digest cycle to loop over all my objects in the collection and change something a hash or a variable.  At that point I could just create a new scope variable called 'fromNow' and set that every so often.  Still a manual step.

Comment: do you have plunker?if possiable please give a pulnker link.it will be better for understanding your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Filters are assumed to be idempotent, that is the same input always leads to the same output. Since `timestamp` doesn't change there's no reason for Angular to do anything.

If your filter is stateful and the output can change with every call then you have to mark it accordingly.

```
function momentFilter() {
  function filter(input, format) {
    if (!input) return null;

    if (format == 'fromNow') {
      var fn =  moment(input).fromNow();
      console.log('fromNow called with: ' + input + ' giving result: ' + fn);
      return fn;
    } 
  };

  filter.$stateful = true;
  return filter;
}
```

Comment: Very true.  However I still think angular is not reevaluating all object in the ng-repeat since none of them changed.  Since its not re-evaluating at a digest cycle then the filter does not get re-run, regardless of stateful.

Comment: @lostintranslation Stateful filters run at least once per digest cycle.