# Auto refresh .filter() scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

How to update the following filter, there is some way?

```
.controller('MainCtrl', ["$rootScope", "$scope", function($rootScope, $scope) {

  $rootScope.number = 1;
  $scope.text = "foo|baz|bar"

}]).filter("MyFormat", ["$rootScope", function($rootScope){
  return function(str){
      return str.split("|")[$rootScope.number]
  }
}])
```

```
<button ng-click="$root.number = 0">0</button><!--foo-->
<button ng-click="$root.number = 1">1</button><!--baz-->
<button ng-click="$root.number = 2">2</button><!--bar-->
<pre>{{text | MyFormat}}</pre>
```

Here is my [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:8aCtdVI5IbIgF9SnGfTl?p=preview) example.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31210363/angular-filtered-result-not-updating-in-the-ui/31211938

Comment: `filter.$stateful`, It's what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

Filters always receive the input value first, but you can pass in other arguments separated by `:` in the filter.  In this case, I've passed in your scope variable number to it.

You don't need $rootScope, you can just use the controller scope.  Also, when you reference a scope variable in your html, you just use the name not the $scope part.  So the cleaned up version looks like:

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])

//Assuming that you do want to use the $rootScope for one reason or another,
//you still access it in the HTML as if it were a scope variable with just
//the name (because it is just a scope variable, it's just one inherited from
//the root).

  .controller('MainCtrl', ["$rootScope", "$scope",
    function($rootScope, $scope) {

      $rootScope.number = 1;
      $scope.text = "foo|baz|bar"

    }
  ])
  .filter("MyFormat", function() {
    return function(str, num) {
      return str.split("|")[num];
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="number = 0">0</button>
    <!--foo-->
    <button ng-click="number = 1">1</button>
    <!--baz-->
    <button ng-click="number = 2">2</button>
    <!--bar-->
    <pre>{{text | MyFormat : number}}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good point, there is no way without passing parameters ?. Because I'm doing a small filter to update languages. I'm using something like this: `config.phrase_website_title | Lang`

Comment: Where are you getting the values for Lang?  I mean how does the filter know which language to provide if it's not set somewhere in a controller or on a scope?

Comment: I made a little change.  Does that help you?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Updated link

[Does this solve your problem?](http://plnkr.co/edit/a0WGCmJTeAA4RKf1Wa4l?p=preview)

I updated filter to take a parameter.

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <pre>{{text | MyFormat:number}}</pre>
  </body>
```

Comment: You are not understanding my question. The current code has no errors, but I like to know a way to update the filter function when the variable `number` is changed.

Comment: Gotcha, can you try the updated link? I think there is no way to make the filter depend on number via rootScope, but we can pass number into the filter via parameter.